# Latency of a Postgres Server in Google Cloud

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform

We are using cloud SQL for postgres. We inserted 1 million records into x number of tables but we are performing the query on a table with only one record. The query we are using is
select id from table_name limit 1.

The query execution time showed in Query insights page is 0.09ms. But the latency when measured from psql is around 250ms. Network latency revealed by 'traceroute' command is 50ms(RTT).

How do I figure out why the total latency of my SQL query is way higher than the actual execution time in the DB server?

Comment: Use psql to execute the same query.  This will tell you if it is specific to dbeaver or not.  But why do you care?  Is that amount of latency in an interactive GUI really bothersome?

Comment: Hi @jjanes, This isn't just about the interactive GUI performance. Even with psql, the time is similar (252.166 ms). The query I used is "select id from table limit 1". According to google cloud, the query execution time is 0.01 ms. We want to understand where is the ~200 ms going assuming network latency is around 50 ms

Answer (score 0):

There are different reasons that can cause a latency issue within your PostgreSQL. You should look deeper to determine the cause of the latency issue. I would suggest:

1. Turn on [**`track_io_timing`**](https://pgpedia.info/t/track_io_timing.html) (*track_io_timing is disabled by default, as it repeatedly queries the operating system for the current time*) in the PostgreSQL configuration so that you can see how long I/O takes.
2. Use [**`EXPLAIN`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) to see how many 8kB blocks are touched.

If the number of blocks is very high, your table is bloated (consists mostly of nothing, *If you delete data, for example, by dropping a table, the space is freed, but it is not reflected in the reported Storage Used of the instance.*), and the sequential scan takes so long because it has to read all that empty space. `VACUUM FULL` command to recover unused space; note that write operations are blocked while the vacuum command is running.

If the block count is as you would expect, the problem is that your storage is too slow.

---

I would also suggest checking out this [troubleshooting guides](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/diagnose-issues) for more information on how to diagnose issues on your PostgreSQL.

Lastly, if latency is still an issue even if you have tried the steps above, I would recommend contacting [**Google Cloud Support**](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) to further investigate and check what's happening on your project.